# Calculate values for missing rows

Tags: sql, missing-data

I have a SQL query which retrieves forecasts per day. If there is a missing forecast for a given "LP" I'd like to calculate it based on the other forecasts. However, with the code below it is not calculating the forecasts when they are missing.

agreementStart, agreementEnd and plantType belong to tbl_p. I tried moving all into the ON-part, but then other rows are included which should not be there and also still no calculation on the missing values. With the current example, missing rows are included in the resultset, but the fields hour00_01, hour01_02, hour02_03 remain null as they are not calculated. The calculation for these columns should be so that if hour00_01 for id 1 is 1, hour00_01 for id 2 is 2 and hour00_01 for id 3 is null, then id hour00_01 for id 3 should be the 3 (the sum of id 1 and 2).

Can anyone point me in the right direction here:

```
declare @startDt date = '2014-12-19' declare @endDt date = '2014-12-19' ; with AllDates as 
( select @startDt as dt union all select dateadd(day, 1, dt) 
from AllDates where dateadd(day, 1, dt) <= @endDt ) 
select dt, m.date, p.lp, p.electricityArea, maxCapacity, SUM(maxCapacity) as c, p.netArea, 
CASE hour00_01 WHEN null THEN maxCapacity*(sum(hour00_01)/sum(maxCapacity)) ELSE hour00_01 END hour00_01, 
CASE hour01_02 WHEN null THEN maxCapacity*(sum(hour01_02)/sum(maxCapacity)) ELSE hour01_02 END hour01_02,
CASE hour02_03 WHEN null THEN maxCapacity*(sum(hour02_03)/sum(maxCapacity)) ELSE hour02_03 END hour02_03
from AllDates ad cross join tbl_p p LEFT JOIN tbl_m m
on p.lp = m.lp and m.date = ad.dt and m.inputType = 'TYPE' where p.plantType = '2' AND (agreementStart <= '2014-12-19' AND agreementEnd >= '2014-12-19')
   GROUP BY 
      ad.dt,
      m.date, 
      p.lp, 
      p.electricityArea, 
      maxCapacity, 
      p.netArea, 
      p.electricityArea, 
      hour00_01, hour01_02, hour02_03
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `WHERE` clause. It is not clear as to which table your `agreementStart` and `agreementEnd` columns belong, but since you have a criteria on these columns and the `plantType` column, you reject any columns that are NULL (i.e. no match in the LEFT JOIN). Therefore, consider moving all your WHERE-criteria into the `ON`-part of the join:

```
. . .
from AllDates ad cross join tbl_p p LEFT JOIN tbl_m m
on p.lp = m.lp and m.date = ad.dt and m.inputType = 'TYPE' AND p.plantType = '2' AND (agreementStart <= '2014-12-19' AND agreementEnd >= '2014-12-19')
GROUP BY 
...
```

Comment: agreementStart, agreementEnd and plantType belong to tbl_p. I tried moving all into the ON-part, but then other rows are included which should not be there and also still no calculation on the missing values. 

With the current example, missing rows are included in the resultset, but the fields hour00_01, hour01_02, hour02_03 remain null as they are not calculated. The calculation for these columns should be so that if hour00_01 for id 1 is 1, hour00_01 for id 2 is 2 and hour00_01 for id 3 is null, then id hour00_01 for id 3 should be the 3 (the sum of id 1 and 2).